# android – How to check if webview is available?

Tags: android, webview

Is there a way to check if webview is available on the device?

Background:
If I add `<uses-feature android:name="android.software.webview"/>` to the Manifest the number of supported devices on Google Play drops from over 12,000 to less than 6,000 devices. So I added `android:required="false"` to this feature. In case webview is available websites should be displayed inside the app otherwise launched in the default browser:

```
String mUrl = "http://www.example.com";
if (*** WHAT TO PUT HERE? ***) {
    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                view.loadUrl(request.toString());
                return false;
            }
        });
    } else {
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    webview.loadUrl(mUrl);
} else {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(mUrl);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**Edit** (to make things clear): `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` is (and always had been) part of the manifest. It’s just the addition of `<uses-feature android:name="android.software.webview" />` which causes the drop of supported devices.

There is someone having the same issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37035282
(unfortunately not answered)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although @vsatkh pointed out that it is not necessarily needed to declare this feature as required, you can check the device’s feature compatibility as follows:

```
getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("android.software.webview")
```

This method returns true or false.

Some additional information about Google Play’s filtering:
Google Play only filters supported devices based on `<uses-feature>` elements declared in the manifest. `<uses-permission>` elements don’t affect Google Play’s filtering unless they imply a feature. `android.permission.INTERNET` does not imply any feature. Permissions that imply features are listed here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions

Comment: With API 20 and newer you can use `PackageManager.FEATURE_WEBVIEW` instead of the hardcoded string.

Answer (score 10):

Alternative solution:
`val hasWebView: Boolean = kotlin.runCatching { CookieManager.getInstance() }.isSuccess`

It works because if WebView is not available then `CookieManager.getInstance()` will throw `AndroidRuntimeException`.

`getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("android.software.webview")` is not reliable. It will return true if the device is supposed to have a webview, but has disabled it in system settings.

I tested it on a Huawei P20 by going to Settings -> Apps -> Android System WebView -> Disable

Comment: Tested in Android 10 and 11. It works!. Added Java version of your code.

Answer (score 7):

## There is a way around: CookieManager

> AFAIK: There is no dedicated API that gives you that information. But what if I told you there is a way around.

As Torkel mentioned, `getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(..)` does not guarantee to tell the Android System WebView is enabled or disabled.

getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(..) will still return true even a user disables the WebView in Settings.

#### CookieManager

So an alternative would be to use `CookieManager`.
An application WebView cookie is managed by `CookieManager`. It throws an exception if you try to create CookieManager instance when the WebView is disabled.

In Kotlin, you can get result from block statements but it is not possible in Java. So you can use Exception Handling logic in a function to decide.

Here is an example

```
public boolean webViewEnabled(){

    try{

       CookieManager.getInstance();
       return true;

    }catch(Exception e){

       return false;

    }

}
```

#### Note:

The current implementation might change in the future, or they might come up with a dedicated API for this. I have tried finding a perfect solution in many forums but this is the closest I have reached.
This solution will prevent your app from crashing but you will still see the error in your logs because CookieManager.getInstance throws an Exception object.

Answer (score 1):

You can read more detail here https://source.android.com/compatibility/android-cdd.pdf.

According to the section WebView Compatibility, android.software.webview feature is indicate that device or oem must provides a complete implementation of the android.webkit.WebView API. So the number of device on play store was drop because actually, most device did not fully implemented all api required by webkit.

So if your web content required certain html5 feature please check here http://mobilehtml5.org/ if your app target kitkat or even lollipop+ then you should be safe.

So there is no need to declare android.software.webview feature unless your web content really need all api of webkit.

Answer (score 0):

As of API 26, you can use `WebView.getCurrentWebViewPackage()` to check if there is a valid WebView installed and active. The CookieManager check can be really slow (upwards of 500ms) and can impact startup performance if the check is happening in the critical path.

From the documentation:

> If WebView has already been loaded into the current process this method will return the package that was used to load it. Otherwise, the package that would be used if the WebView was loaded right now will be returned; this does not cause WebView to be loaded, so this information may become outdated at any time.
>
> The WebView package changes either when the current WebView package is updated, disabled, or uninstalled. It can also be changed through a Developer Setting. If the WebView package changes, any app process that has loaded WebView will be killed. The next time the app starts and loads WebView it will use the new WebView package instead.
>
> @return the current WebView package, or {@code null} if there is none.

You can verify that this is working as expected by swapping the WebView implementation and then calling this method to list the PackageName (e.g if you're running the dev/beta Chrome WebViews) by calling:

`WebView.getCurrentWebViewPackage()?.packageName`

You can test disabled state by running the following ADB command (although you might need an emulator running as root via `adb root`): `adb shell pm disable <webview-package-id>`.

Answer (score -2):

WebView has been had in Android API 1 so it's always available what's not it's the internet connection 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html
In you manifest you need internet permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Sure. This permission has already been part of the manifest. If webview is always available why does the number of supported devices drop?

Comment: WebView is NOT always available.

Comment: e.g. during `WebView` update installation - may trigger automatically anytime (if auto-update set in store app), even during other app running, which is using `WebView`. I've read that some never Android version (10?) is fixing this by installing update (of any app) in some background and only when app isn't used then old package is replaced by new